# Put all div in a row

Tags: css, html

How would you put all of these `<div>`s in a row?

```
  <div style="background-color: aquamarine; margin:50px">
        <div style="background-color: azure;width:25%;">
            1
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: darkolivegreen;width:25%;">
            2
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: darkorange;width:25%;">
            3
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: bisque;width:25%;">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the awesome `display:table`.

```
<div style="background-color: aquamarine; margin:50px; display:table">
    <div style="background-color: azure;width:25%;display:table-cell">
        1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: darkolivegreen;width:25%;display:table-cell">
        2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: darkorange;width:25%;display:table-cell">
        3
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: bisque;width:25%;display:table-cell">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

In fact, you don't even need to specify widths for the inner divs. With `table-layout:fixed` the browser will automatically calculate the widths and lay it out nicely. :)
Be sure to specify a width on the parent div though.

```
<div style="background-color: aquamarine; margin:50px; width:100%; display:table; table-layout:fixed">
    <div style="background-color: azure;display:table-cell">
        1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: darkolivegreen;display:table-cell">
        2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: darkorange;display:table-cell">
        3
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: bisque;display:table-cell">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: great Code. Thank you  Harsh

Answer (score 1):

you need to use floats

give this four inner divs a class  and then use css `float: left`

Comment: Just adding float:left won't do it. Additionally, you'll also have to specify a explicit height for the parent div, or clear the float, otherwise parent will collapse.